# Wordpress - Create a author.php, but only for a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I wanted to create a new page similar to `author.php` in wordpress, but that lists only a specific Custom Post Type. It is important to have both pages: `author.php` for regular posts, and this new `author-custom-post.php` only for the Custom Post Type.

The usage is that the first one will list the blog posts, and the other one will list the author's cientific publications, each one in its own page.

And, of course, it should have a link to this `author-custom-post.php` that I can use in the author bio.

I could only manage to find pages listing both things together, but nothing about listing in different pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you know how to make custom post types and then fetch the data??

Comment: Do you mean like a normal archive for a Custom Post Type? If so, I know, but not for each of the authors. What I manage to do was to show the custom post types in `author.php` with/instead of regular posts. But not two separated pages, that is what I need.

Comment: create a `author-custom-post.php` and fetch the data from the custom post type and make that php file a template to include on any page you want the viewer to see?

Comment: It don't need to be included, but just work like an `author.php`. I can have a link to the `author.php` page with `<?php the_author_link(); ?> `, and I wanted to have something similar to that, but with a link to this `author-custom-post.php`.